# Sliding side panel z-index problems in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a sliding side panel for a Google Map, and am running into problems getting the slider to display over the map while keeping the map clickable.

The only way I've been able to get the panel to display is to set the Z-index of the map to a negative number, which makes it unclickable. How can I get the panel to slide out over the map, while keeping the map interactive?

[I've created a JSFiddle here where you can see the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/k4g7zqus/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="slide-panel">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="opener"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</a>

        <div style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:100%; padding:10px;">
            <h3>Search</h3>     
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div id="map">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slide-panel {
    width:300px;
    max-width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    padding:0px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-left:-310px;
}
#opener {
   float:right;
   margin:75vh -80px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

#map {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#opener').on('click', function() {       
        var panel = $('#slide-panel');
        if (panel.hasClass("visible")) {
            panel.removeClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'-300px'}); } else {
            panel.addClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'0px'});
        }   
        return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle link

Changes in **CSS**

```
#slide-panel {
    width:300px;
    max-width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    padding:0px;
    background:#fff;
   position: relative; /*changes done */ 
   z-index: 999; /*changes done */ 
    margin-left: -315px; /*changes done */ 
}
#opener {
  /*  float:right; 
   margin:75vh -80px 0px 0px; */ /*changes done */ 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    z-index: 999; /*changes done */ 
position: absolute; /*changes done */ 
/* left: 0; */
bottom: 50px; /*changes done */ 
right: -80px; /*changes done */ 
}

#map {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /* z-index:-1; */ /*changes done */ 
}
```

changes in **Javascript**

```
$('#opener').on('click', function() {       
        var panel = $('#slide-panel');
        if (panel.hasClass("visible")) {
            panel.removeClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'-315px'});}else { 
            panel.addClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'-20px'});
        }   
        return false;   
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/bgmdr8bx/2/)

Answer (score 1):

To put the panel into a stacking context, it can be given a relative position (and thus keep it in the normal flow) and z-index greater, than the map has.

```
#slide-panel{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    ...
}
#map{
    z-index:1;
}
```

[Live.](http://jsfiddle.net/k4g7zqus/2/)